# How can I make this construction simpler, like with classes or functions in python?

Tags: python, list, function, class, if-statement

```
print(
    "1. Engine block \n"
    "2. Pistons \n"
    "3. Crankshaft \n"
    "4. Camshaft \n"
    "5. Cylinder head \n"
    "6. Connecting Rod \n"
)

part = int(input("Choose an engine part to show you details about it: "))

if part == 1:
    print("Engine block")
elif part == 2:
    print("Pistons")
elif part == 3:
    print("Crankshaft")
```

I have 26 statements like these and I wonder if I can make it simpler with classes,
functions, lists or something I can't find a way??

Comment: You could see what's common between those 26 statements and put it on a function

Comment: I thought of that, but I want to output every part for itself, like pistons, crankshaft and camshaft are in common with engine block, wouldn't that rip off parts of their description, wouldn't that show one description for 4 parts?

Comment: you can do a function where you pass a dict and print the info like the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using something like this:

```
def info_about(parts):
    info = list(parts.values())
    print("\n".join(f"{i+1}.\t\t{name}" for i, name in enumerate(parts)))

    print()
    while True:
        part = input("Choose an engine part to show you details about it: ")
        if not part.isnumeric():
            print("Please enter a valid number")
            continue

        part = int(part)
        if part > len(info) or part < 1:
            print("Please enter a valid number")
            continue
        break

    print(info[part-1])

parts = {
    "Engine block":         "Info about engine block",
    "Pistons":              "Info about pistons",
    "Crankshaft":           "Info about crankshaft",
    "Camshaft":             "Info about camshaft",
    "Cylinder head":        "Info about cylinder head",
    "Connecting Rod":       "Info about connecting rod",
}

info_about(parts)
```

This now checks the input to ensure that it is valid - that it's numeric, and that it's between 1 and the number of parts.

Comment: It wasnt me the downvote, but what if I input 'test'...You just get error.

Comment: Ok, have fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: This is great, I can't think of any improvements, perfectly written, much help, I wanted to ask how can I  check input but you read my mind :D

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with Question and answer. Also add function in the class to check if the input is same as the Answer and return the result accordingly. You can use the regular expression to fetch the value of right answer from the Question text.

Comment: That is something to think of, Ill try and play with my code with classes and functions-

Answer (score 0):

If you really want an extra function

```
print(
    "1. Engine block\n"
    "2. Pistons\n"
    "3. Crankshaft\n"
    "4. Camshaft\n"
    "5. Cylinder head\n"
    "6. Connecting Rod\n"
)

def list_dict():
    return {1: "Engine block", 2: "Pistons", 3: "Crankshaft"}

def ans(part):
    return list_dict()[part]


part = int(input("Choose an engine part to show you details about it: "))
print(ans(part))
```

Comment: Extra function is always a good idea, Ill play with my code and try to squeeze it in, great work